# Запуск php скрипта в October CMS через javascript

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, cms, october

Возник такой вопрос, как в octobercms обработать скрипт  php. Нужно запустить отправку данных на почту. Ко всему хочется обойтись без плагинов. Октябрьские страницы CMS могут выполнять только функции и имеют все файлы расширения htm, просто вставить код не получиться. Куда и что надо записать и положить . Как можно реализовать данный модуль и функционал в Octobrcms
Форма имеет такой вид:

```
<form class="form">
    <img src="{{ 'assets/img/modal-close.svg'|theme }}" class="close-modal">
    <h2 class="form-title">Заполните заявку на бесплатную<br> консультацию специалиста</h2>
    <div class="form-cont">
        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="userName" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="userPhone" placeholder="Телефон">
        <textarea class="form-textarea" name="userMess" placeholder="Комментарий"></textarea>
        <button class="first-btn  form-btn" type="button">Оставить заявку</button>
        <p class="got_it">Ваша заявка принята, ожидайте звонка</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ловим переменные с помощью javaScript:

```
function Correct() {
    $('.form-btn').hide()
    $('.got_it').show()
    $('input[type=text]').val('')
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.form-btn').show()
        $('.got_it').hide()
    }, 5000)
}
$('.form-btn').on('click', function () {
    let name = $(this).parents('form').find('input[name="userName"]').val()
    let phone = $(this).parents('form').find('input[name="userPhone"]').val()
    let errors = 0
    if (name == "") {
        $(this).parents('form').find('input[name=userName]').css({'border-color':'red'})
        ++errors
    }
    if(phone == ""){
        $(this).parents('form').find('input[name="userPhone"]').css({'border-color':'red'})
    }
    if (errors == 0) {
        $(this).parents('form').find('input[type=text]').css({'border-color':'rgba(6, 22, 41, 0.3)'})
        let str = $(this).parents('form').serialize()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: str,
            url: "assets/form.php",
            success: Correct()
        });
    }

})
```

Сам файл form.php:

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST['userName'];
$Phone  = $_POST['userPhone'];
$Serv = $_POST['userServ'];
$Size = $_POST['userSize'];
$Mess = $_POST['userMess'];

$fuulmessage = "Имя: " . $Name .
    "\nТелефон: " . $Phone .
    "\nУслуга: " . $Serv .
    "\nКомментарий: " . $Mess .
    "\nРазмер участка: " . $Size;

$messsage = $fuulmessage;
$to = 'info@mail.ru.ru';
$subject = "Новая заявка!";
$subject = "=?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=";
$from = 'info@mail.ru';
$headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-to: $from\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $messsage, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: [Creating Contact Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ki8eRIdipKc&ab_channel=WatchandLearn). На Вашем месте я бы лучше воспользовался плагином, так как Ваш файл `form.php` не является безопасным.

Comment: @Simon Добрый день, я все проделал через базу почему-то записывает только комментарий и не отправляет  поля имя и телефон